# NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure at sending ByteArrayOutputStream through REST service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy

I have to send a ByteArrayOutputStream through a rest service, and I got this exception:

`org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/html;charset="iso-8859-1" and type class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`

I don't understand why and I have to make it work.

Here is my rest service:

```
@POST
@Path("/exported")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public ByteArrayOutputStream getExported(Wrapper wrapper) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = null;

    os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        os.write("TTT".getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return os;

}
```

Here is my client:

```
    ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:8081/restws/rest/rrr/exported");
    request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    request.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, new Wrapper(
            listOf Objects));

    ClientResponse<ByteArrayOutputStream> response = request
            .post(ByteArrayOutputStream.class);

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = response.getEntity();

    return "success";
```

Everything in the class containing this method works, except this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestEasy doesn't know who to convert your ByteArrayOutputStream into something that can be sent over HTTP. Read up on [RESTEasy Content Marshalling](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#Content_Marshalling_Providers) and then either use a different content type and/or use a different data type that is automatically handled and/or write a content marshalling provider to handle your ByteArrayOutStream.